# find primitive elements in $\mathbb Z_2[x]/\langle x^5+x^2+1\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Somebody can help me with this exercise?

> How many primitive elements are there in $\frac{\mathbb{Z}_2[x]}{\langle x^5+x^2+1 \rangle}$?

Thank you.

Comment: Z2[x]/ <x^5+x^2+1>

Answer (score 1):

The primitive elements are exactly the generators of the multiplicative group, which is always cyclic for a finite field.

So it is enough to find how many elements the field has.